# Saving a form and reloading state with bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I submit a form to save a user profile I want to show the user an alert message to show if the record was saved successfully or not.  I have 3 bootstrap tabs and the form I want to save is on the active tab.

I believe the alert isn't displaying because the `$state` needs reloaded.  I'm not sure how to do this.  If this page was a separate route I could probably do `$state.reload()` or something similar.  I can click to a different tab and back and the alert will show.

I've tried: `$state.transitionTo('myprofile', null, {reload: true, notify:true});`  No luck with that though.

HTML that displays the alert:

```
<div ng-if="profilesaved == 'saved'" class="alert alert-success fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong> Your profile has been saved
</div>
```

The relevant state:

```
.state('myprofile', {
    url: '/my-profile',
    templateUrl: 'pages/my-profile.html',
    controller: 'MyProfileController as myprofile',
    resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
      "firebaseUser": ["$firebaseAuthService", function($firebaseAuthService) {
        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError
        return $firebaseAuthService.$requireSignIn();
      }]
    }           
})
```

The function that sets the DB record.

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var record = firebase.database().ref().child('myprofile/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                 .set({
                        name: $scope.profile.name,
                        address: $scope.profile.address
                    }

                 ) 
                 .then(function(data) {
                    console.log('profile saved');
                    $scope.profilesaved = "saved";


                 })
                 .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('profile save failed');
                    $scope.profilesaved = "save-failed";

                 });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to solve this but this did the trick:

```
 .then(function(data) {
    console.log('profile saved');
    $scope.profilesaved = "saved";
    $scope.$apply();
    $timeout(function(){$state.reload();}, 4000);
 })
```